# When & where can I access "Red Hart Halla" in Dragon Age Inquisition?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Red Hart Halla is part of Dragon Age Inquisition.

**Where (or when) can I access it? Do any quests need to be completed beforehand?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sadly took me forever to figure out. Go to the war room and select the Orlais side of the table, theres a mission that gets you the Red Hart the moment you accept it.